# importJSON and concatenate function not working together

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I am trying to use concatentate to create the input parameters with a variable for the importJSON function.  The concatenated string looks and works fine if I copy it into the importJSON function but if I reference the string as part of the function or use concatenate in the function I get an invalid argument error.

Here is the concatenate string.  Cell I7 is the date. For example 2017-11-27.

`=concatenate("""https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo""",",","""","/Time Series (Daily)/",I7,"/4. close""", ", ","""noHeaders""")`

Here is the output string with the date variable:

`"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo","/Time Series (Daily)/2017-11-27/4. close", "noHeaders"`

This works:

`=importJSON("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo","/Time Series (Daily)/2017-11-27/4. close", "noHeaders")`

These dont work:

`=importJSON(concatenate("""https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo""",",","""","/Time Series (Daily)/",I7,"/4. close""", ", ","""noHeaders"""))`

`=importJSON(K9)` >> K9 is cell where the concatenate function is

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the extra set of quotes. When referencing a cell or using a formula within the importJSON function, quotes are not needed.